# Show loading page not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this markup:

```
<div class="container" id="logo" style="text-align:center;">
  //other loading stuff
  <a href="" id="enter" onclick="EnterSite()">Enter Website</a>
</div>  

<div id="content">
 //main content
</div>
```

At the **top** before the closing `head` tag I have:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#enter').hide();
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#enter').show();
    });
</script>
```

And at the bottom I have (before the closing `body` tag):

```
function EnterSite() {
        $("#enter").click(function(){
            $("#content").show(2000);
        });
    }
```

and CSS:

```
#logo {
  z-index: 99;
}
#content {
   display: none;
}
```

But it just shows the **`logo`** div and clicking on the **`Enter Website`** link does nothing.

what I want to do is show the **`logo`** div till the page is loaded (window.load) with the **Enter Website** link hidden. Once the page is loaded then show the link which on click will show the **`content`** div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using an `onclick` handler, to bind a new click handler using jQuery. The new click handler won't fire first time you click on the `<a>` tag, because the event has already happened.

Either remove the `onclick` from markup and just use

```
$(function(){
  $("#enter").hide().click(function(){
        $("#content").show(2000);
   });
})
```

Or change to:

```
function EnterSite() {       
       $("#content").show(2000);

}
```

I suggest using first solution and avoid mixing inline script and jQuery to keep all your script unobtrusive and easier to maintain

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#enter').show();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#enter").click(function () {
        $("#content").show(2000);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6g3MT/1/)