# Loading page not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this markup:

```
<div id="logo" style="text-align:center;">
    <p>AXIS'14</p>
    <a id="enter" onclick="EnterSite()">Enter Website</a><br>
</div>

<div id="content">
  //content here
</div>
```

And javascript:

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
         // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
         $("#enter").fadeIn(1000);
        });
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function EnterSite() {
            $("#logo").fadeOut(500);      
            $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
        });
                //this initialize the grid gallery

        $(function() {
            $( '#sg-panel-container' ).gridgallery();
        });
</script>
```

What I want is after window is loaded the **`Enter Website`** link should appear which on click will fade out the **`logo`** div and show the **`content`** div. Currently what is happening is **[here](http://credible-nation-380.appspot.com/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877706/show-loading-page-not-working-properly/19877791#19877791](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877706/show-loading-page-not-working-properly/19877791#19877791)

Comment: with that solution the grid gallery doesn't work

Comment: then why did you accept the answer?

Comment: coz the answer was correct for what I had asked. there was nothing about the grid in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably do:

```
<script>
        $(window).load(function(){
         // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
         $("#enter").fadeIn(1000);
        });
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#enter").click(function () {
                $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#enter").click(function () {
                $( '#sg-panel-container').gridgallery();
            });
        });
</script>
```